# Regex regular expression minimum character amount

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^[8][0][1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

How would I make it so that I have this expression but also so that the minimum amount of characters is 6.

Thanks

Comment: Your pattern already matches 6 numbers.  What is your question?

Comment: It exactly does what you ask for. It matches 6 digits at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern already matches what you asked for. If you want to simplify it you can write it as:

```
^80[1-3][0-9]{3}
```

And if you want at least 6 characters but remaining being only 0-9 digits, then:

```
^80[1-3][0-9]{3,}$
```